# Android - Como definir um item selecionado de um Spinner para uma string?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

Estou com uma dúvida em meu código, estou tentando pegar o valor do Spinner e gravar ele no banco, mas não consigo fazer com que o spinner tenha valor de String.
No caso ele está me dando erro na hora do *setText*, no final do código. "Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'"

```
public class editarContato extends Activity {

Spinner spinner; String[] arraySpinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editar_contato);

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
this.arraySpinner = new String[] {"SP", "RJ", "SC"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

btAtualizar   =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.atualizar);

carregaDetalhesContato();

btAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datasource = new DBAdapter(editarContato.this);
            datasource.open();
            contato = datasource.getContato(idContato);
            datasource.close();
            datasource.AlterarContato(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            datasource.close();
}
});

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent,View view, int pos, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){}
    });
}

public void carregaDetalhesContato() {

    idContato = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);

    datasource = new DBAdapter(this);
    datasource.open();
    contato = datasource.getContato(idContato);
    datasource.close();

spinner.setText(contato.getSpinner());
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) não possui o método `setText`. Para isto você pode utilizar o método `setSelection(int index)`. Por exemplo, setar seleção para SP:

```
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition("SP"))
```